# O que é a parte da frente do texto?

Tags: interpretação

Estamos em uma discussão intensa aqui no escritório sobre o que é a parte da frente de um texto. Espero poder contar com a ajuda de vocês para uma decisão final...

Como pode ser visto nesse exemplo (https://material.angular.io/components/badge/examples):

[image: exemplo]

Conceitualmente, os ícones, botões e badges **estão na frente do texto? Ou não?**

Se o cliente pediu para colocar o botão na frente do texto em cada item dessa lista, o pedido foi atendido ou não da forma como está?

EDIT1: Não vale dizer 'pergunte ao cliente'. rsrsrs... Quero saber qual o entendimento mais comum para as pessoas.

Pergunta original: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/416907/o-que-é-a-parte-da-frente-do-texto/](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/416907/o-que-%C3%A9-a-parte-da-frente-do-texto/)

Comment: Ao meu ver, os elementos supracitados estão após ou ao lado direito do texto. No caso do `tail` (Linux), ele pega o final do texto e não a parte da frete ou de trás. Numa corrida, alguém vai estar na frente ou atrás, pois um estará correndo de frente (ou de costas) para o outro (a menos que estejam de lado ). Na língua portuguesa perguntamos se a pontuação vai após "x" palavra em vez na frente dela. **Adendo:** Se o cliente falar que "quero na frente do texto", questione-o para esclarecer a dúvida.

Comment: Para mim, *na frente do texto* é ambíguo: tanto poderia significar imediatamente à esquerda (quem está a ler encontra o ícone antes de chegar ao texto), imediatamente à direita (o texto avança da esquerda para a direita, logo o ícone à direita está mais adiantado, logo na frente), ou até um ícone meio transparente sobreposto ao texto (como o vidro está à frente da foto emoldurada). Eu sou português, e aqui em Portugal eu diria nestas situações, ***à** frente*; mas espero estar a compreender bem o que pretendes.

Comment: No Brasil, talvez aí em Portugal, "na" e "à" seriam equivalente nesse caso.

Comment: Sérgio, foi o que eu pensei. Em Portugal não usamos *na frente* nestes casos (mas parece-me que já se usou). Noutros caso usa-se mas é diferente. Exemplo: *sentado na frente do avião* está dentro do avião; *sentado à frente do avião* está fora.

Comment: Em Portugal, eu diria que o botão está à direita do texto. Eu sou programador e se me dissessem para colocar o botão na frente do texto eu ia pensar em profundidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste contexto, ***na frente de*** ou ***à frente de*** (neste contexto equivalentes no Brasil; em Portugal só se diz *à frente de*) é ambíguo: encontra-se no Google Books e na internet em geral, mas o significado pretendido é  **’à direita de’** nuns casos, **’à esquerda de’** noutros, e **’sobreposto a’** (com o texto como pano de fundo) noutros ainda. Os exemplos de *na/à frente do texto* são limitados, de modo que alarguei a busca a *frente da palavra, frente do nome, ícone na/à frente*, que são análogos. Mostro alguns exemplos (negrito meu em todas as citações):

### *Na/à frente de* = ’à direita de’

Neste [página](https://tecsysteminformatica.com.br/2018/04/23/inserir-uma-imagem-na-assinatura-do-webmail-roundclube/), “[n]o campo ‘Endereço da imagem’ terá um **ícone na frente**” refere-se à imagem seguinte, com o ícone à direita do campo:
[image]

Em [*BrOffice.org* (2007, p. 45)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=X8Sugx4ioeAC&pg=PA45&dq=%22bot%C3%A3o%20%C3%A0%20frente%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwu9SV-rflAhUK6OAKHfMlASgQ6AEINjAB#v=onepage&q=%22bot%C3%A3o%20%C3%A0%20frente%22&f=false) temos:
[image]

No StackOverflow em português temos a pergunta [Como colocar uma imagem na frente de um botão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49797/como-colocar-uma-imagem-na-frente-de-um-bot%C3%A3o); na resposta aceite, a imagem está à direita do botão.

O mesmo se passa falando de texto em geral num livro ou documento de papel, como se vê nestes exemplos do Google Books:

> Imaginem os designativos físico, biológico, exato, humano, sociológico, psicológico, filosófico, astronômico etc. **à frente da palavra “jornalismo”**! A expressão **“jornalismo científico”** já soa meio contraditória.
>   [Sérgio Vilas Boas, *Formação e informação científica*, São Paulo, 2005](https://books.google.pt/books?id=AJp-u_AeRNAC&pg=PA7&dq=%22%C3%A0%20frente%20da%20palavra%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL8pqpg6nlAhXS7eAKHQDOAzgQ6AEIPDAC#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A0%20frente%20da%20palavra%22&f=false)
>
> cubo: o bebê bebeu coca
>   Para ser escrito **na frente da palavra “cubo”** a professora perguntava: “o que o bebê fez?” e lhes dizia que escrevessem a resposta **na frente da palavra “cubo”.**
>   [*Cadernos de pesquisa*, n. 72-79, 1990](https://books.google.pt/books?id=pYoQAAAAYAAJ&q=%22na%20frente%20da%20palavra%22&dq=%22na%20frente%20da%20palavra%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3ruKDgqnlAhWyA2MBHbQTAO4Q6AEIOjAC)
>
> […] escreverá o nome de cada um em um livro, que intitulará «Registo dos Libertos». **Na frente do nome** se fará a descripção da pessoa, da sua idade provavel, e signaes corporeos […]
>   [*Boletim do Conselho Ultramarino*, vol.  2, Lisboa, 1869](https://books.google.pt/books?id=hB22i-HvJbIC&pg=PA310&dq=%22na%20frente%20do%20nome%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi94pDtnKvlAhWx0eAKHS8TAM8Q6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=%22na%20frente%20do%20nome%22&f=false)

### *Na/à frente de* = ’à esquerda de’

[Neste manual](https://www2.camara.leg.br/a-camara/estruturaadm/diretorias/diretoria-legislativa/estrutura-1/conof/sisconof_manual), “**ícone à frente das colunas ‘Núcleo’** ou **‘consulto/assistente’” refere-se a:

[image]

[Neste documento](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/pt/extragear-graphics/kphotoalbum/chp-browsing.html), “cada pessoa tem o mesmo **ícone à frente do seu nome**”, refere-se a:

[image]

[Neste outro manual](https://pmp.pr.gov.br/intranet/licitacao/images/manualFornecedor.pdf), “**ícone na frente da palavra edital**” refere-se a:

[image]

Mais dois exemplos do Google Books:

> Como **uma Psicologia** pode se produzir como realidade?¹
>   […]
>   ¹ Como se perceberá, apesar de utilizarmos em alguns momentos deste capítulo o artigo definido (a) **à frente da palavra Psicologia** e em outras partes o indefinido (uma) […]
>   [Neuza Guareschi e outros, *Psiclologia, formação, política e produção em saúde*, Porto Alegre, 2010](https://books.google.pt/books?id=l3oFQaIEOksC&pg=PA13&dq=%22%C3%A0%20frente%20da%20palavra%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL8pqpg6nlAhXS7eAKHQDOAzgQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A0%20frente%20da%20palavra%22&f=false)
>
> Desta forma um pastor é pastor não porque recebeu o chamado, porque possui o dom para exercer a função, mas sim porque se formou pastor. A conclusão do curso lhe confere o direito de receber óleo sobre a cabeça e então passar a fazer uso de **um “Pr.” à frente do nome** […]
>   [Luciano Silva, *A Igreja de Casa em Casa*, 2009](https://books.google.pt/books?id=JpTdE8Qh9soC&pg=PT141&dq=%22%C3%A0%20frente%20do%20nome%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE16m-nqvlAhWwAGMBHYD-AG4Q6AEIRDAD#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A0%20frente%20do%20nome%22&f=false)

### *Na/à frente de* = ’sobreposto a’

Exemplos disto são mais difíceis de encontrar, mas temos um que todos conhecemos na formatação de imagens no Word. Em “moldar texto” ou “opções de esquema” (versões brasileira e portuguesa, creio) “à frente do texto” significa ’sobreposto ao texto’ (ocultando-o; nunca percebi qual fosse o objetivo disto, mas adiante) como se pode ver [no vídeo em support.office.com](https://support.office.com/pt-pt/article/moldar-texto-%C3%A0-volta-de-uma-imagem-bdbbe1fe-c089-4b5c-b85c-43997da64a12) ao segundo 37 (é preciso selecionar legendas):

[image]

Outro exemplo [nesta pergunta no StackOverflow em português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397143/como-posso-definir-um-elemento-sobre-outro-elemento). Pela descrição do problema, e execução das rotinas na pergunta e reposta aceite, compreende-se que perguntador e respondente entenderam *na frende de* como ’sobreposto a’.

### Minha interpretação

No Google Books, *na/à frente da palavra* ou *do nome* significa ’à esquerda’ e ’à direita’ com frequência semelhantes. Já com ícones e botões, encontrei bastantes mais exemplos com o significado ’à direita’. Mas isto poderá ser simplesmente por ser essa a posição mais habitual do ícone ou botão na tela de um computador.

Parece-me que o que se passa é que os falantes conseguem conceber uma coisa como estando à frente de um segmento de texto quer essa coisa esteja à esquerda, à direita ou sobreposta ao texto. Já tinha sido esta a minha intuição inicial, expressa num comentário à pergunta. A razão por que pensei isso foi que *à frente* pode significar coisas diferentes::

- Um interpretação é que *à frente* é para onde nós vamos. Logo, numa linha de texto, para a frente é para a direita, porque o texto avança da esquerda para a direita, portanto um ícone à direita do texto está à frente do texto.
- Mas também se compreende que se diga que um ícone à esquerda do texto está à frente dele, porque nós, lendo a partir da esquerda, encontramos o ícone antes de chegar ao tal texto. Compare-se com uma bicicleta encostada a um poste no outro lado da rua, parcialmente oculta por um carro **à frente dela**. Aqui o *à frente* nem tem nada que ver com a roda dianteira da bicicleta; significa apenas que do nosso ponto de vista o carro está antes da bicicleta.
- E uma imagem à frente do texto pode ainda estar sobreposta, com o texto como pano de fundo. Nesta interpretação, a analogia com o carro à frente da bicicleta no outra lado da rua é ainda mais direta.

Quando se passa de objetos físicos no espaço para uma linha de texto, não é claro qual das noções acima é mais válida. Por isto não me surpreende que *na/à frente de* [segmento de texto] tenha sido usado para significar quer ’à direita’ quer ’à esquerda’ quer ’sobreposto’. Talvez por causa desta ambiguidade, *na/à frente de* para significar ’à direita de’ ou ’à esquerda de’ é relativamente raro: é muito mais frequente *à direita de, depois de, após* ou *a seguir a* para um lado, e *à esquerda de* ou *antes de* para o outro. Para ’sobreposto’ não, sei, porque não é tão comum termos coisas sobrepostas ao texto.

Comment:      

Comment: Poderia me explicar como não seria mais lógico  ou natural dizer: antes ou depois de um elemento (em formatação de texto)?

Comment: @Lambie, quê?! Onde é que eu digo que *antes* ou *depois* não é mais lógico e natural? Quando muito sugiro o contrário, nomeadamente, digo que *na/à frente de (texto)* é ambíguo e, citando a minha conclusão, "*na/à frente da palavra* ou *do nome* [tem] sido usado para significar quer *à direita de* quer *à esquerda de*. Talvez por causa desta ambivalência, *na/à frente de* é relativamente raro: no Google Books são muito mais frequentes *à direita de, **depois de**, após* ou *a seguir a* para um lado, e *à esquerda de* ou ***antes de*** para o outro."

Comment: O problema para mim é que sua resposta nem menciona a **formatação** de textos, que é o assunto da pergunta...nesse sentido, não há nenhuma dúvida...Não vejo porque falar no que se encontra em livros tería muita relevância...

Comment: @Lambie, a pergunta é, e passo a citar, "os ícones, botões e badges **estão na frente do texto? Ou não?"** e "Quero saber **qual o entendimento mais comum para as pessoas"**. Repara que a pergunta não é *como é que se diz isto corretamente "em formatação de texto"*. Portanto eu respondi à pergunta: há pessoas que dizem ou escrevem "*na frente do texto*", e quando o fazem, **qual o entendimento mais comum [disso] para as pessoas?**. Repara que a pergunta diz simplesmente *pessoas*; não diz *pessoas especialistas "em formatação de texto"*. Para isso teria perguntado no StackOverflow.

Comment: Jacinto: o contexto é formatação. Não há nenhuma dúvida. Porque não admiti-lo? "**Estamos em uma discussão intensa aqui no *escritório*.** E se o perguntador não sabe, e até posta texto que claramente mostra um contexto de formatação, que aprenda pois! Assim ele vai ficar mais assegurado do seu emprego, nos dois sentidos do termo. Quem trabalha em escritório com texto, deve saber **ou aprender** um mínimo sobre formatação, me parece.

Comment: @Lambie, a pergunta é, e cito, **"qual o entendimento mais comum para as pessoas"** de **"na frente do texto"**. Não estou a inventar ou a interpretar; estou simplesmente a citar.

Comment: na frente do texto é antes do texto. A minha respota mostra exatamente o texto dele. Se fala em alinhar um texto antes ou depois de um elemento. Acho que vocês todos são um pouco: uvas amargas [piada com o inglês, para quem não pega]. :)

Answer (score 1):

Vejo que no contexto da informática *a expressão "na frente" se relaciona com*:

- `prepend` ao invés de `append`
- `head` ao invés de `footer` (no HTML)
- `:before` ao invés de `:after` (no CSS)
- `insertAt(0)` ao invés de `push`
- (e muitos outros exemplos)

Além disso...

- Penso que no HTML o marcador da lista `UL` fica na frente do texto. *(como se vê nesta lista)*
- No Linux, o comando `tail` com certeza *não pega a frente* do texto.

Em termos de dia-a-dia: **O botão está depois, logo não está na frente.**

- Se eu digo "chegue na *frente* nessa corrida", estou dizendo "chegue *antes* dos outros corredores".
- Ou ainda, "cheguei depois de você na festa", logo "você chegou na minha frente".
- Se você escreve uma frase qualquer "é uma casa muito bonita", e eu peço "coloque a palavra 'essa' na frente". A frase ficaria "*essa* é uma casa muito bonita".

A conclusão que chego é: no printscreen acima **o botão não está na frente do texto**.

Comment: É uma casa muito bonita, essa. ;)

Comment: Como é que chegou a ideia que na frente é equivalente a aqueles pontos todos?

Comment: Porque fica sem sentido dizer que são "atrás", ou "depois"...

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a resposta é muito simples...

**Leia de trás pra frente.**

De onde para onde você estará lendo?

Logo, *o botão não está na frente.*

Answer (score -1):

Isso tudo faz parte do que se chama **formatação.**

Se fala em: alinhamento de texto ou elemento ou colocação do texto ou elemento.

Os tal badges não são botões, exatamente segundo o site angular.io. Também, no texto da pergunta dizem: **button with a badge.** Então, são dois conceitos diferentes.

**Badges are small status descriptors for UI [user interface] elements. A badge consists of a small circle, typically containing a number or other short set of characters, that appears in proximity to another object.** [badges are not buttons per se]
[badges][1](https://material.angular.io/components/badge/overview)

Mas é verdade que para falar em alinhamento pode-se dizer [botão para badge](https://www.raffcom.com.br/blog/o-que-e-ui/).

**"O User Interface – ou interface do usuário – é tudo aquilo que é perceptível visualmente em alguma plataforma e leva o usuário a uma interação positiva.  Pode ser um botão, um menu diferente ou até mesmo um som."**

Este site tem uma boa explicação dos elementos de interface do usuário:

[elementos](https://www.chiefofdesign.com.br/ui-design-elementos-da-interface-do-usuario/)

Naquele site, se fala em notificação:

Uma notificação é uma sinalização. Trata-se de **uma mensagem de atualização** que anuncia algo novo ou importante. Elas podem ser utilizadas para indicar uma tarefa como concluída ou para mensagens de erro ou aviso.

[image]

Me parece que o mais normal aqui seria dizer:

> ***O texto se alinha antes ou depois da notificação, ou do botão, ou do botão com circulo ou elemento.***

Não se diria (formalmente) em formatação **em frente ou detrás.** Eu não estou traduzindo badge ou button. A minha resposta é para a ideia de colocação de um elemento ou texto numa formatação.

Achei para a ideia de badge: **circulo com número**

[whappsup e circulo com número](https://maiochristopher.webnode.com.br/apps/gbwhatsapp/funcoes/a2/a2-2/)

Claro, badge é crachá ou emblema, também.

Comment: Não percebo bem como isto responde à pergunta. O perguntador diz que tem um texto de requisitos onde lhe é dito "para colocar o botão na frente do texto em cada item dessa lista", e quer saber qual a interpretação mais correta ou provável do requisito - se deve colocar o botão antes ou depois do texto de cada item.

Comment: @ANeves E eu não percebo de nenhuma maneira como não responde à pergunta. Talvez a linguagem de formatação (de texto) seja algo que desconheças? Não se fala em "a parte da frente de um texto" nessa linguagem. Se diz: antes ou depois de um elemento.  Os que colocam voto negativo na minha resposta mostram uma grande falta de conhecimento....que  pena.

Comment: Concordo com o @ANeves. O que se diria "em formatação de texto", formalmente ou não, é interessante mas secundário para esta pergunta. Há pessoas que falam de ícones, etc. ***na/à frente*** do texto, e o perguntador pergunta explicitamente qual é **o entendimento mais comum para as pessoas** de *na frente do texto*. Isto é a pergunta, e esta resposta não lhe responde.

Comment: Tenho de ler melhor a resposta, mas a imagem é exatamente o que eu estava a querer dizer no comentário que deixei na pergunta, essa notificação está à frente da imagem. É esse o meu entendimento de à frente num contexto de programação. Talvez eu faça uma resposta também.

Comment: @Lambie eu não estou a concordar nem a discordar de ti. Essa pergunta não tem a ver com programação, mas esse contexto pode mudar muita coisa.

Comment: @JorgeB Francamente, em todos os anos que trabalho com textos e imagens, eu sempre falo "antes do/de e depois de/do x" e nunca "a frente". O carro ficou em frente da casa. Isso sim. A frase se coloca antes do elemento. Não considero que essa pergunta tem a ver com "programação". As frases se colocam em uma ou outra posição. Ou seja: são antepostas ou pos-postas.

Comment: @Lambie e se na pergunta em vez do texto fosse uma imagem, a tua resposta teria a mesma validade? Colocar um botão em frente a uma imagem já faria sentido?! Ainda é formatação de texto ou é UI de uma aplicação?

Comment: @JorgeB Credo,vocês são bem complicados. Você pode dizer o que quiser. Mas eu acho que eu **diria pessoalmente** para um objeto no espaço: um carro em frenté ou detrás da casa. E para textos e elementos em páginas (tipo HTML) eu diria: antes ou depois do elemento ou antes ou depois da frase. **Eu não falei em "programação"**, eu falei sobre tudo em **formatação**.